# I need to rewrite my page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to use SEO friendly adresses changing:

**pruebas.qstion.net/vote.php?ranking=The_best_dogs**

to

**pruebas.qstion.net/vote/The_best_dogs**

I did a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^vote.php?ranking=[0-9]+
RewriteRule ^$ http://pruebas.qstion.net/vote/ [L,R=301]
```

But it doesnt work, and I don't know why. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess url rewrite querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827625/htaccess-url-rewrite-querystring)

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ranking=(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://pruebas.qstion.net/vote/%1? [R=301,NC,L]
```

So it is grabbing the variable `ranking=` and taking whatever is associated to it. Then using a 301 redirection it attaches that onto the end of the URL via `%1`.

You'll notice I've added a `?` on to the end of the rewrite, this is simply to stop the original query from appearing on the end of the URL.

So you would get http://pruebas.qstion.net/vote/The_best_dogs if the query was `ranking=The_best_dogs`.

Make sure you clear your cache **before** testing this.

Comment: Yes it works, thank you. But The page cannot be found!. Is it possible to validate at the same time the new address?