# Mod Rewrite - is there a faster way?

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite

im building a site with lots of parameters. At the moment i'm using this Code in my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /epo

RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?section=$1&content=$2&site=$3&param=$4&param2=$5 [QSA]
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?section=$1&content=$2&site=$3&subsite=$4 [QSA]
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?section=$1&content=$2&site=$3 [QSA]
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?section=$1&content=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule (.*)/$ index.php?section=$1 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^\.]+[^/]$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

I'm new to mod_rewrite, thats why this code is a mess. Is there any better way to deal with all these parameters? The last two lines are just there to add a "/" at the end in case there is none. Would be also great if someone could explain their code, so i can understand what i did wrong :)

Comment: read my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637335/url-rewriting-in-php-when-several-values-are-being-passed-in-the-url/14637516#14637516

Comment: Downvote was unnecessary - looks like a valid question to me. I second the link above - but with context - it's helpful, when you have complicated rules AND the opportunity to use a 'front-controller' style of architecture to redirect all requests to your index.php and then make exceptions (e.g. for images, js, css, etc).

Comment: thanks for this link, but i dont fully unterstand it: What do you mean with "With this rules everything is forwared to index.php. So you are free to implement every url logic with PHP." Can you provide me with a simple PHP example, so i can use your mod_rewrite code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Personally I redirect all request to a single file and then handle it from there.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [QSA]
```

And then in index.php use something like

```
$params = explode('/', $_GET['path'];

$section = $params[0];
$content = $params[1];
$site    = $params[2];
$subsite = $params[3];
//etc.
```

Keep in mind that you do need some extra validation on all parameters

Comment: Thanks, is this the best way of dealing with multiple parameters? Im always afraid of slowdowns caused by all these parameters :) Another question: What other validation do i need for these params?

Comment: Depending on your settings `$params[3]` could give a warning if only 2 params are set. Also use regular validation to make sure the params are what you expect them to be. (numeric or string, sql escape it, etc)

Comment: Thank you very much, now i get it :) I used your code and used a foreach loop to check if the params are set.

Answer (score 1):

It is similar to Hugo's example but without `GET` param:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

in `PHP` you can do following:

```
$pathInfo = pathinfo($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$baseUrl = $pathInfo['dirname'];
$baseFile = $pathInfo['basename'];
$url = rtrim(str_replace([$baseUrl, '/'.$baseFile], '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), '/');
$method = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
$isModRewrite = array_key_exists('HTTP_MOD_REWRITE', $_SERVER);
```

Your url's can now look something like:

```
http://www.yourserver.com/param1/param2
```

OR (if mod rewrite is not enabled)

```
http://www.yourserver.com/index.php/param1/param2
```

In both ways the `$url` variable looks like `/param1/param2`

You can do `explode` on this string or feed a PHP routing library with this string for extracting your parameters.

PHP routing example libraries:

https://github.com/robap/php-router

https://github.com/deceze/Kunststube-Router

Comment: Thanks for your code, that way i can get rid of the GET Parameter as well :) This code works for me.