# Mod_rewrite - Create Clean URLs

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

We would like to create clean URLs to our website. I have searched that how could this be done and I have found a code snippet, however it doesn't fulfil my requirements. Here I'm going to explain what we basically want.

This is the basic website's URL: **http://www.test.com**

We have a "pages" menu, which lists specific pages which users can see. It looks like the following: **http://www.test.com/pages.php**

We basically want that when someone visits this **/pages.php** it should redirect them to **/pages** (or with full URL: **test.com/pages**) or not redirect, just show a page not found.

It should also work with any of these possible configurations:

- /page
- /page/
- /page.php

I have looked at Stackowerflow's system, and it is working the way we would actually want it. So every time I'm looking at either:

- stackoverflow.com/questions
- stackoverflow.com/questions/
- stackoverflow.com/questions.php - showing a page not found site

This is basically what I need. I have tried this code, but it does not work fully for my needs:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

I'd be pleased if anyone could write a clear explanation how can this be achieved. Also if you find this post duplicated, please link me the EXACT post, because I have been searching for this exact question, but I didn't find any answers to it.

Thanks

Comment: see my answers [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637335/url-rewriting-in-php-when-several-values-are-being-passed-in-the-url/14637516#14637516](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637335/url-rewriting-in-php-when-several-values-are-being-passed-in-the-url/14637516#14637516) and [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496979/mod-rewrite-is-there-a-faster-way/15497491#15497491](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496979/mod-rewrite-is-there-a-faster-way/15497491#15497491)

Comment: I have checed these and they are focusing on how to generate a Clean URL from an URL like this: http://www.test.com/pages.php?id=123 However do you have any solution which could simply turns pages.php into /pages ?

Answer (score 0):

Below, first rule will 301 redirect *.php to URL without .php and second rule will handle all other urls by adding ".php" to it:

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*?)\.php$
    RewriteRule ^/.*$ /%1 [R=301,QSA,L]

    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /$1.php
```

For example,

`/page.php` will redirect to `/page` and will process `page.php`.

Comment: It actually does not do anything with the page, even if I visit: /page.php or /page or /page/

Comment: Shoud I just use these? Nothing else?

Comment: I would remove other rules at least to see if it's working.  But my rule will cause problems with, for example, static files (*.jpg for example) so you will probably need some additional conditions.

Answer (score 0):

OK, write something like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName deli.localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/deli/
    <Directory /var/www/deli/>
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all

                RewriteEngine on

                ## Externally redirect clients directly requesting .(php|aspx|html|htm|pl|cgi|asp)+ page 
                ## URIs to extensionless URIs
                ## If client request header contains php,aspx,html or htm file extension, redirect
                ## It avoids an infinite loop since "THE_REQUEST" is what the UA asks for, not what the 
                ## server translates it to on the second pass.
                ## THE_REQUEST syntax is something like: GET /page.html HTTP/1.0
                RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^.]+)\.(php|aspx|html|htm|pl|cgi|asp)+(/.*)?\ HTTP [NC]
                RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.(php|aspx|html|htm|pl|cgi|asp)+(/.*)?$ http://xyz.com/$1$3 [NC,R=301,L]


                FileETag none





                ErrorDocument 401 /401.php
                ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
                ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
                ErrorDocument 500 /500.php
                ErrorDocument 503 /503.php
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score -1):

Found this on another post.  It apparently strips extensions .php, .html, .cgi off the url.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.cgi -f
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.cgi [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.cgi -f
RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That is cleaning URLs extension from the file, not really making it to behave like a SEO url coming (aka slug) from the database (the usual pattern).