# Mod_Rewrite PHP issue

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, uri, friendly-url

I have actually tried the tutorial stated in here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls

I have tried to use the PHP version of the Tutorial. However it doesn't seems to work. In fact it looks a little bit illogical for me.

This is the code which I'd need to place to the .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

As I have tested this actually redirects everything to the index.php file. So I have inserted this code to my index.php file:

```
$request  = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 

$params     = split("/", $request);  


$safe_pages = array("login");  

if(in_array($params[0], $safe_pages)) {  
echo 'ok'; //insert a file here
} else {  
echo 'not ok'; //header to 403.php
```

}

This code is quite starightforward. If the URI is /login it should echo: "ok" (insert the file there).

However whenever I type: **mywebsite.com/login**  it just always gives me the index.php, with the message: "not ok" so something should be wrong with the php code I guess.

Comment: Please contact the author of that tutorial if you have an understanding question about it. You can also keep the discussion related to that tutorial in the comments of that tutorial.

Comment: Use `print_r($params);` to see where that code went wrong; probably `[0]`.

Comment: Also please solve / answer you previous question which seems to be of the same topic first: [Mod_rewrite - Create Clean URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15952942/2261774).

Comment: Noone could answer my previous question. Also I have learned since than and I have tested more examples, but noone seems to work for me. Actually noone could provide me with a good answer...

Comment: @mario I have did that, and I'm getting the follwoing: login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are missing one more method on the .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: If the method of getting the requested page is via the `REQUEST_URI`, you don't need to redirect it to a named parameter - though it is suggested, it is not required as you imply. ^^

Comment: @Radical_Activity to do it this way, you would say `$request= $_GET['q'];`

Comment: @Jon hmm it does actually work, now, but I don't understand why?? Why q?

Comment: @Radical_Activity Because of this line: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]` the parenthesis around `.*` captures everything and puts it in to `$1`, which is then assigned by `?q=$1`.  You can change it to anything you want like `?myVar=$1` and then you would access it with `$_GET['myVar'];`

Comment: @Jon it makes sense now. However is there any way that it can be done without $_GET variables? Or are these secure, because $_GET doesn't looks so secure in my eye. What's if I write: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php$1 [L,QSA] is it correct? If yes, how can I capture that and do things in my PHP code?

Comment: @Radical_Activity Define secure.  It is a way to access information that is passed, and works just as well as checking the `request_uri`, except with needing to do less to get it working. ^^

Comment: I mean, is this the total same than using 'request_uri'? So there is no security exploit which someone could do in this case and they can't in the 'request_uri' case? Also I have found another problem. When I have added another page: "pages.php" and I have wanted to visit http://mywebsite.com/pages it did load well. However when I have written a slash at the end like this: http://mywebsite.com/pages/ it did not have the css formatting :( Why is that?

Comment: @Radical_Activity There is no security hole which can be exploited from rewriting to a named parameter ^^  Also, adding the slash at the end is causing the CSS/JS includes to fail as the browser views it as a different location.  Once you start making 'pretty' url's, give absolute paths to the includes, ie `/css/mycss.css` instead of `css/mycss.css` so that the browser knows where to look in relation to the domain.

Comment: @Jon ah thank you, this makes sense. :) Also may I ask you if there is any method that if someone wants to visit the `pages.php` he/she can't get the page and they get a redirection? Or maybe I could do that I place these `pages.php` files outside of the root directory, maybe 1folder over the root and I call them from there? Is it a good solution? So I'd actually just have the `index.php` file at my root directory. Is it a solution you would do? Or can you please tell me what would you prefer to do when you build a huge website?

Comment: @Radical_Activity Personally, I don't `include` a page based on the conditions. But you can put `define('IN_SITE', true);` on the index, and within the pages you'd include check to see `if(!defined('IN_SITE')) { //redirect to index.php; }` (or, alternatively, redirect to a 404 page ^^)

Comment: @Jon Hmm, and if I put that define function on the index and check it on, for example: login.php, how will my Pretty URL work? I mean, If I'm using this code, how will it know that it needs to redirect? I migh be a little bit confusing, but I don't understand this. (Sorry for the lot of questions but you are the one who actually understands my problem and I want to ask you till you're here :)):` $request  = $_GET['q']; 
 $params     = split("/", $request);
 $safe_pages = array("login","profile");
 if(in_array($params[0], $safe_pages)) {  
define('IN_SITE', true);
 exit();
 } else {  

   }  `

Comment: @Radical_Activity It's ok. ^^  at the very top on `index.php` put `define('IN_SITE', true);` then on any page you will include in the, ie on `page.php` or `login.php`, at the very top of that page, you would put `if(!defined('IN_SITE')) { header("Location: /index.php"); exit; }` or something similar. ^^ (it won't affect the url rewriting as including pages from php doesn't pass through the `.htaccess`.)

Comment: Hmm, I have inserted that `define` code at the top of the `index.php` and inserted the redirector code to login.php. However when I visit: `mysite.com/login` it just gives me `login.php` and under it, I got the `index.php` so it is kinda messed up. Maybe because I have removed the `exit function` after including? Is it necessary? So my actual including code looks like this after splitting: `if(in_array($params[0], $safe_pages)) {  
  include($params[0].".php");
 } `

Comment: @Radical_Activity Please zip up everything in your root and email it to me (contact info on my profile).  That way I can better see what's going wrong.

Comment: Oh I got it now man!!! :) Btw I have sent you a contact email :) But I have understand now what you have meant! This is awesome! Thanks a lot man, I think I'm complete now :) Thanks to you. I have been searching for this for days, you have saved me man! IS there any way that I can thank you? Maybe give you some rep? If yes, please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

This should suport url like 'page/item'

```
<?php
$request  = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; 

$params     = explode("/", $request);  


$safe_pages = array("login");  

if(in_array($params[0], $safe_pages)) {  
    echo 'ok'; //insert a file here
} else {  
    echo 'not ok'; //header to 403.php
}
?>
```

This dont work with url like 'page/item'
This should work:

```
<?php
$request  = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 

$params     = explode("/", $request);  


$safe_pages = array("login");  

$last_item = count($params)-1;

if(in_array($params[$last_item], $safe_pages)) {  
    echo 'ok'; //insert a file here
} else {  
    echo 'not ok'; //header to 403.php
}
```

You are testing the wrong item. You should check for the string 'login' in the end of the array. And the function split is depreciated, use [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: why not do `$last_item = end($params);` and then `in_array($last_item, $safe_pages)`?  Though, if you ever want to expand and allow `myPage/how-to`, etc, this whole method no longer works. ^^