# Reduce Codeigniter Segment across entire codebase?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I'm working with someone else's application and [trying to clean up the urls a bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20127779/is-this-a-job-for-mod-rewrite).  Turns out the site is built on Codeigniter.  Using routing, I was able to remove unwanted segments from the url but now the variable content in the templates are broken.  They are broken because something like `$heroImg = $this->uri->segment(5)` should now use `segment(3)` .

I know that I could manually reduce the segment value in the seemingly hundred of places in the code across the dozens of files, but I was wondering if anyone had a suggestions to do this either via PHP or a  an editor?  I use notepad++ and Komodo.

Answer (score 0):

You can sure replace `$this->uri->segment(5)` with `$this->uri->segment(3)`.

I use SublimeText's **Search & Replace in Files** function to do such kind of jobs. 

Notepad++ also has a similar function, I guess.

Comment: Ya that is pretty much what I ended up doing.  I was looking for some kind of magic solution that did find segment(x) and replace with segment(x-2)

Comment: I did a quick try & found out that you could do that *magically* too.
In your routes.php you can have a route added that maps your 5th segment to 3rd segment.
Then you can use the $this->uri->rsegments(3) to get the actual 5th segment in your url.